# Javascript regex to escape quotes (but not escape already escaped quotes)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a JavaScript regex which will escape single quotes but it should not escape single quotes which are already escaped.

Comment: [Why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: If the single quote is JS escaped then as far as JS is concerned it will be just a single quote.

Answer (score 14):

Ideally, you want every match to start exactly where the previous match ended.  Otherwise it's too easy to get out of sync with the escape sequences.  @outis's regex comes close, but it fails to escape the second single-quote in `'\\'`.  After the first match, it has to match at least one non-backslash and one single-quote, which it can't do.  If there are any more characters, it skips ahead and starts matching after the second single-quote.

Try this one instead:

```
result = subject.replace(/([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'/g, "$1\\'");
```

This is an example of Friedl's "unrolled loop" pattern:

`normal * (special normal *) *`

`[^'\\]*` is the "normal *" part; it gobbles up any number of characters other than single-quotes or backslashes.  If the next character is a backslash, `\\.` ("special") consumes that and the next character (backslash, single-quote, or whatever) and `[^'\\]*` takes over again.  Repeat as needed.

The key point is that the regex never skips ahead and it never backtracks.  If it sees a backslash, it *always* consumes that and the next character, so it never gets out of sync.

Comment: Did you ever know that you're my hero? That you're the wind beneath my wings?

Comment: This doesn't work for double quoted strings, if you switch the single  quotes for doubles in the regex: `str.replace(/([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"/g, '$1\\"');`

Comment: @Inn0vative1: It works for me: ([demo](http://ideone.com/TnOmcW)).   What input are you using?

Comment: @AlanMoore thanks for the response. I must have made a typo or something. It was "seemingly" not working for me when the quote marks were already escaped. Just tried again and it's working fine. Upvoted!!

Comment: This fails for `\'`

Answer (score 4):

If there are an even number of backslashes, they only quote each other. Thus a character is quoted if it has an odd number of preceding backslashes. Since JS doesn't support lookbehind, you'll need to capture the leading non-backslash and include it in the replacement.

```
var escquote = /((^|[^\\])(\\\\)*)'/g
"a ' b \' c \\' d".replace(escquote, "$1\\'")
```

However, if this is for any sort of security purposes, it's the wrong approach for a number of reasons. Firstly, if you're doing this client side, it isn't secure. Second, quoting should be handled when data is sent to a subsystem using the methods provided by the subsystem. For example, if the data is going to a relational database, you should use prepared statements and parameterize the varying data. Prepared statement parameters aren't vulnerale to injection.

Comment: This fails on `'\\'`; see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can write:

```
var escaped = original.replace(/\\['\\]|'/g, function (s) {
    if (s == "'") return "\\'";
    else return s;
});
```

If there's a contiguous sequence of escaped-escapes, it skips them all. If at the end there's a "\'", then the quote is already escaped and is also skipped. If at the end there's a "'", the quote is escaped.

Comment: @outis: I don't know what you mean; my code supports that case.

Comment: @Downvoter: care to explain why? (Unless you were the downvoter, outis, in which case -- care to test the code?)

Comment: I did test it, but I must have made a mistake on the test and it returned the wrong result. Edited & upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution

```
/[^\\]\'|^\'/g
```

Comment: What if the original string is `\\'`? Then the single-quote is preceded by a backslash, but *not* already escaped.