# Regex for VHDL string literal

Tags: regex, vhdl

I'm trying to parse my VHDL code for some additional checks.

I'm looking for a regular expression that looks for string literals. A string literal is enclosed by double quotation marks as so:

```
" {characters} "
```

The problem currently is the following requirement:

If a quotation-mark value is to be represented in the
sequence of character values, then a pair of adjacent quotation marks must be written at the corresponding
place within the string literal.

This means the following are legal string literals:

```
""""  
" random stuff "" random stuff "
```

I'm not sure if :

```
("(("")*[^\n"]*)*")
```

covers it sufficiently

Comment: so how are you dealing with escaped quotes, there's no point with """" being a legal string literal, so you can have this: """"""""""?  it's a string literal, or it's just a double quote floating in space, you can't have it every which way.

Comment: If you aren't sure, you can just try your regex: `find -name '*.vhdl' | xargs cat | perl -ne 'print if /regex/' > yourResult.txt` Then see how the result differs from just searching for lines containing `"`: `find -name '*.vhdl' | xargs cat | perl -ne 'print if /"/' > allQuotes.txt`.  Just counting the number of lines might be helpful: `wc -l yourResult.txt allQuotes.txt`

Comment: curious, sebs, do you not want to match this unescaped double quote as well?   'dkfasdfasdfasd"kjlkdsajf' ?  why not?

Comment: @sweaver: In vhdl is no such thing as an escaped character. Also string literals can be only one line long. A newline is a seperator between lexical elements in VHDL.  Your 'dkfasdfasdfasd"kjlkdsajf' is unvalid in VHDL. Single quotes can only enclose single characters.

Comment: You may want to consider a lexer/parser generator like ANTLR.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make it full proof, you may need a *full lexer* instead of a regular expression. The proposals I read here can cause false positives, for example:

```
a <= '"'; -- assigns the character " to signal a.
```

Your regex will match `"'; -- assigns the character "` here.

Then again, if your code does not contain any strange double quotes in comments or in character literals, or in strings, the simplest regex will work for you.

Comment: I guess I could create a regex with multiple groups ruling out the `'"'` case like so. `('.')|([^"\n]|"")*`  Most regex engines evaluate the regex from left to right. If there is something in the second group it would be recognized as valid string literal.

Comment: @sebs Your proposed regex does not yet take into account the quotes in comments (or block comments) or extended identifiers. It just gets complicated really fast. I wanted to point out that Regex might not be the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 3):

I hope `/"([^"]|"")+"/` will work for most of your need.  Please try it.

Edit: `+` should be `*`.  The OP himself knows regex better than me!

Answer (score 0):

you could try this: (pseudocode */regex/*)

```
/(?<!["\\])"(\w\s)+"(?!")/
```

then use regex backreferences:

```
replace = "\"" + match.$1 + "\""
```

note: this expression makes a naive attempt to *not match already escaped double quotes* (look back and not see a `\` or `"` , but since `\\"` would actually be a regular double quote preceded by a regular backslash, [the more you think about it the more complicated it gets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8874584/244811).