# Strip quotes with Regex in JQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

Im trying to get rid of all quotations in a string.

*example string*

> ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3" ,"value 4"]

*this is what I tried, and it worked on one of the Regex online testers. Probably not JQuery though.

```
string  = string.replace(new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z ,]/g,""));
```

Comment: why not just replace " instead what not to replace

Comment: what vks said, though OP will one day run into problems with escaped quotes, so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874509/javascript-regex-to-escape-quotes-but-not-escape-already-escaped-quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it will remove all `"`s from your string:

```
var x = '["value 1", "value 2", "value 3" ,"value 4"]';

newString  = x.replace(/"/g, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the quotes only:

```
string = string.replace(new RegExp('"','g'),'');
```

Comment: It has to be `string  = string.replace(new RegExp('"','g'),'');` when you use the `RegExp`-constructor

Comment: `/ab+c/i; ===
new RegExp("ab+c", "i")`;

Answer (score 1):

If the string is

```
 var string = '["value 1", "value 2", "value 3" ,"value 4"]';
```

Then you can remove the quotes using:

```
string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,\[\]]/g,"");
```