# Escape string for concatentaion with string and template literals

Tags: javascript

I need to concatenate untrusted* data into a javascript string, but I need it to work for all types of strings (single quoted, double quoted, or backtick quoted)
And ideally, I need it to work for multiple string types at once

I could use string replace, but this is usually a bad idea.

I was using JSON.stringify, but this only escapes double quotes, not single or backtick.

Other answers that I've found deal with escaping only a single type of quote at a time (and never backticks).

An example of what I need:

```
untrustedData = 'a String with \'single quotes\', \"double quotes\" and \`backticks\` in it';
const someJS = `console.log(\`the thing is "${escapingFunctionHere(untrustedString)}"\`)`
```

`someJS` will be passed to `new Function`

* N.B. In my context "untrusted" here doesn't mean potentially malicous, but it does need to cope with quotes, escapes and the like.

I am building javascript code dynamically, the constructed code will not be in any way web-facing. In fact its likely that I am the only one who will use this tool directly or indirectly.

*I am happy to accept the minimal associated risks*

NOTE TO OTHERS: Be sure you understand the risks before doing this kind of thing.

For those interested, I am writing a parser creator. Given an input ebnf grammar file, it will output a JS class that can be used to parse things.
I really do need to output code here.

Comment: I would show the expected output but I'll probably get it wrong somehow...

Comment: "*someJS will be passed to new Function*" that seems the thing to try and change, rather than "how do I dynamically produce valid JS code from random input".

Comment: @VLAZ I am open to suggestions on that front. I really do need to output JS that will be executed though. Ultimately whether you use `new Function`, `eval` or write the output to a file and then `require` it, the escaping requirements will be the same...

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the bigger picture and why this is all "necessary" to begin with…?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is escape single quotes `'`, double quotes `"` and backticks `` ` ``, then using [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to prepend a backslash `\` should be enough:

```js
untrustedData.replace(/['"`]/g, '\\$&')
```

```js
const untrustedData = 'I \'am\' "a `string`"';
console.log(untrustedData);
const escapedData = untrustedData.replace(/['"`]/g, '\\$&');
console.log(escapedData);
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't handle `\\` in the input string. What else does it not handle? This is why I didn't want a string replace answer

Comment: What do you expect `'\'` to become in the output?
This question seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874509/javascript-regex-to-escape-quotes-but-not-escape-already-escaped-quotes