# separating an array inside a .map function

Tags: javascript, next.js

i have a database that exports json. the exported json looks like this.

```
{"Drinks":[{
"name":"name",
"discription":"discription",
"image":"image",
"ingredients":"['ingredients1', 'ingredients2']",
"instructions":"instructions",
"author":"author"
}]}
```

using the .map function i can print out everything there currently, the problem being that i want to seprate out the ingredients. i asumed that using another .map function inside the first one would do the trick but i keep getting

```
TypeError: p.ingredients.map is not a function
```

here is the trouble some code

```
    <ul>
    <div className="grid">
      {Drinks.map(p => (

      <a className="card_red">

        <h3>{p.name}</h3>

        <p>
          <b> {p.discription} <br/> <br/> </b>

          {
            p.ingredients.map(i => ( <b> {i} <br/> <br/> </b> 
            ))}

            <b> {p.ingredients} <br/> <br/> </b>

          <b> {p.instructions} <br/> <br/> </b>
          <b> {p.up_votes} <br/> <br/> </b>
          <b> {p.downvotes} <br/> <br/> </b>
          <b> {p.author} <br/> </b>

        </p>
      </a>
    ))}
    </div>
    </ul>
```

the output of witch is with the second .map function removed is,
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kMUr.png)

my expected output would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEFud.png)

Comment: Your current problem is that the value of `ingredients` is a string, not an array. How is this data set? Ideal you want to make sure it's an array when the value is set. Converting it back to an array is a lot harder, especially since it does **not** conform to the JSON format since you use single quotes. You could use `eval()`, but generally speaking `eval` is evil.

Comment: fix the string making it json then parse it: https://playcode.io/703889/

Answer (score 1):

Your 'ingredients' is a String, there are double-quotes around the array in the JSON. Also that string is not even valid JSON, as the string values inside it are delimited by single-quotes instead of double-quotes. Instead it should look like this:

```
{"Drinks":[{
"name":"name",
"discription":"discription",
"image":"image",
"ingredients":["ingredients1", "ingredients2"],
"instructions":"instructions",
"author":"author"
}]}
```

As you comment that you're unable to fix this issue at it's source, what you might do is this (where you now have `p.ingredients.map`):

```
// Convert p.ingredients to valid JSON by replacing any (non-escaped) single-quotes with double-quotes 
// Search-regex is adopted from this anwer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875837/1005404
const jsonizedIngredients = p.ingredients.replace(/([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'/g, '$1\"');
// Parse the valid json
const ingredients = JSON.parse(jsonizedIngredients);
// Apply the mapping function
ingredients.map(...);
```

Comment: *"i have a database that exports json"*, note that the answer is not valid JSON. Each ingredient in the array should be wrapped with double quotes instead of single quotes. JSON does not allow single quotes as string delimiters.

Comment: unfortunately the database im pulling from is being written to by may other bots/apps so it would require a rewrite of all those bots, i would really love a contained solution in js. maybe a way to convert it to a proper json?

Comment: just checked the db, it looks like ingredients is stored as mediumtext

Comment: Pressed enter in my previous comment expecting a new line but it immediately got posted instead  Anyway:
If you're absolutely sure there's never going to be any single quotes inside the values in your 'array' then you might first replace all single quotes by double quotes so that it becomes valid JSON, then use JSON.parse: `JSON.parse(p.ingredients.replace(/'/g, "\"")).map()`
As other suggested eval() is an option, but it introduces sever security issues, as any actual code in your string Array would also be executed: `eval("[console.log('hi there')]")`

Comment: If you do need to support escaped single quotes in your array values then try this: `const jsonized = p.ingredients.replace(/([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'/g, '$1\"');
const parsed = JSON.parse(jsonized);
parsed.map();`(inspired on (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875837/1005404)[this] answer)

Comment: @alexhansen I've updated the answer to include the additional steps described in the comments. If it solves your question then it would be appreciated if you could accept it.